# Why is there a starting backtick in bash's unexpected EOF `"' error

Tags: bash

Given:

```
echo '"Number' > temp.sh
./temp.sh
```

With this script, Bash prints this error message:

```
./temp.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

Why does it print out `` `"' `` versus something like `'"'`?

PS: I tried searching for a answer but only got answers to questions asking for help debugging this error. Instead I want to know why the error message prints outs a starting backtick versus a single quote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using separate open and close quotes is historically considered good form in English, and an essential part of proper typography. This fell partially out of style due to cost-saving measures (and attempts to conserve the limited 7-bit ASCII character space), but has never completely disappeared.

From [Practical Typography](http://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html):

> Curly quotes are the quo­ta­tion marks used in good ty­pog­ra­phy.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Typewriters_and_early_computers):

> "Ambidextrous" quotation marks were introduced on typewriters to reduce the number of keys on the keyboard, and were inherited by computer keyboards and character sets. Some computer systems designed in the past had character sets with proper opening and closing quotes. However, the ASCII character set, which has been used on a wide variety of computers since the 1960s, only contains a straight single quote (U+0027 ' apostrophe) and double quote (U+0022 " quotation mark).

...and, a few paragraphs below, referring *specifically* to the (mis)use of the backtick as an open quote:

> These same systems often drew the grave accent (`` ` ``, U+0060) as an open quote glyph (actually a high-reversed-9 glyph, to preserve some usability as a grave). This gives a proper appearance at the cost of semantic correctness. Nothing similar was available for the double quote, so many people resorted to using two single quotes for double quotes, which would look like the following: [...]

Comment: Oh the long absurd legacy of programming... :), and then one day someone, I would love to find the commit but that's probably long lost, the GNU authors(?) added a back tick and 20+ years later it's still there.